# Multiple LISTAGG rows for a certain number of records

Tags: oracle11g, listagg

I haven't been able to solve this puzzle. I would like to split a listagg query by every 3rd tracking number for the order.

```
Order Tracking
1     123
1     432
1     566 
1     867
1     999 
2     321
2     742
2     456
2     987
```

My current output is lumping all the tracking numbers per order together

```
Order Tracking
1     123, 432, 566, 867, 999
2     321, 742, 456, 987
```

My desired results splits up with a max of 3 per row.

```
Order Tracking
1     123, 432, 566
1     867, 999
2     321, 742, 456
2     987
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` here in a CTE to impose groupings of three on the orders:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT "Order", Tracking,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Order" ORDER BY Tracking) - 1) / 3 AS grp
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    "Order",
    LISTAGG(Tracking, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Tracking) "Tracking"
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    "Order", grp
ORDER BY
    "Order", grp;
```